# flutter-maplibre-gl not show icons of POI with provided correct style.json

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox-gl, maplibre-gl, flutter-mapbox-gl

I am working on the map and hosting map on my own server. In addition, I also working to create my own style.json using maputnik and some manual works, and customize the icon with "sprite" as well. Moreover, I have the web app map running perfectly using Maplibre GL JS. And the problem come with my flutter mobile application, with exactly the same style.json & sprite but I dont see any icon show on the map. For example, icon of transportations, restaurants, banks...ect.

```
return MaplibreMap(
              // zoom: _style!.zoom ?? 18,
              doubleClickZoomEnabled: true,
              minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(0, 24),
              compassEnabled: false,
              styleString: _urlMapTheme(),
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
              tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: currentPosition ?? centerPoint,
                zoom: 18,
                bearing: 0,
                tilt: 5,
              ),
              onMapCreated: (MaplibreMapController controller) {
                debugPrint(
                    '--- [HomePage][MaplibreMap] onMapCreated');
                // _controller = controller.setGeoJsonSource(sourceId, geojson)
              },
              onStyleLoadedCallback: () {
                debugPrint(
                    '--- [HomePage][MaplibreMap] ');
              },
              onMapClick: (Point<double> point, LatLng latLng) {},
              trackCameraPosition: true,
              myLocationRenderMode: MyLocationRenderMode.NORMAL,
              annotationOrder: const [
                AnnotationType.line,
                AnnotationType.circle,
                AnnotationType.fill,
                AnnotationType.symbol,
              ],
              annotationConsumeTapEvents: const [
                AnnotationType.fill,
                AnnotationType.line,
                AnnotationType.circle,
                AnnotationType.symbol
              ],
            );
```

My puspec.yaml:

```
  maplibre_gl:
git:
  url: https://github.com/m0nac0/flutter-maplibre-gl.git
  ref: release-0.16.0
```

Comment: I solved the issue. Just place answer here for anyone who struggling with this like me.
The reason is that my style url have a "space". With web application, it's okay to hash the space to %20. However, in flutter mobile application, when url have space, they cannot get the target sprite. Just remove space and it works